# calling qsort with a pointer to a c++ function

Tags: c++

I have found a book that states that if you want to use a function from the C standard library which takes a function pointer as an argument (for example qsort), the function of which you want to pass the function pointer needs to be a C function and therefore declared as extern "C".

e.g.

```
extern "C" {
  int foo(void const* a, void const* b) {...}
}

... 
qsort(some_array, some_num, some_size, &foo);
```

I would not be surprised if this is just wrong information, however - I'm not sure, so: is this correct?

Comment: See: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html

Comment: @Thomi: `foo` above is not a member function; therefore the provided FAQ entry doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: [33.2] actually mentions it, see my comment to the first answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll give you that. But a link to a large page without explanation isn't the most useful comment in the world. Even better would have been a [direct link to the given section](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot depends on whether you're interested in a practical answer for the compiler you're using right now, or whether you care about a theoretical answer that covers all possible conforming implementations of C++. In theory it's necessary. In reality, you can usually get by without it.

The real question is whether your compiler uses a different calling convention for calling a global C++ function than when calling a C function. *Most* compilers use the same calling convention either way, so the call will work without the `extern "C"` declaration.

The standard doesn't guarantee that though, so in theory there could be a compiler that used different calling conventions for the two. At least offhand, I don't know of a compiler like that, but given the number of compilers around, it wouldn't surprise me terribly if there was one that I don't know about.

OTOH, it does raise another question: if you're using C++, why are you using `qsort` at all? In C++, `std::sort` is almost always preferable -- easier to use and usually faster as well.

Comment: Easier to use, faster and **type-safe**.

Comment: `qsort` might be special, though. The C++ standard requires that `qsort`, `bsearch` and `atexit` *must* be declared by the implementation with "C++" linkage *as well as* "C" linkage. For other standard C functions it's implementation-defined what linkage they have. I don't know what the intent or effect of this is, and I haven't seen anything to say whether this has a consequence for the function pointer parameter, but it can't be a coincidence that these standard C functions that take callbacks, have this additional requirement in C++.

Comment: Also, the C++ standard says that signal handlers must have "C" linkage. It doesn't explicitly say this for the callbacks of the three functions with "C++" linkage. So I'm pretty sure something is going on, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 5):

This is incorrect information.

`extern C` is needed when you need to link a C++ library into a C binary; it allows the C linker to find the function names.  This is not an issue with function pointers (as the function is not referenced by name in the C code).

Comment: but then, the link @thomi posted as a comment also states:  
`it actually would have to be an extern "C" non-member function to be correct, since "C linkage" doesn't only cover things like name mangling, but also calling conventions, which might be different between C and C++.`  
in [33.2] or do I have a misunderstanding?

Comment: @DaVinci: This is a fair point, albeit one that doesn't come up in practice that often, because compilers for C++ and C on the same platform generally use the same calling convention.

Comment: @DaVinci:  Technicalities aside, in general you can also use static *member* functions where a pointer to a C function is required.